# Является ли NEWID() равномерно распределённой функцией?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Достаточно ли написать в SQL Server 2017

```
SELECT x FROM y
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

для того, чтобы быть точно уверенным в том что все созданные значения будут равномерно распределёнными между собой?

Т.к. это GUID v4, то генерация основана на псевдослучайных числах. Но будет ли всё множество созданных чисел `NEWID()` создано с одинаковой вероятностью или шанс оказаться в каком-то диапазоне чисел отличится от общего?

Если не является, то является ли следующее выражение равномерно распределённым?

```
SELECT x FROM y
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Comment: Я припоминаю, что несколько лет назад на en.SO кто-то давал ссылку в коментарии на блог или статью, где это исследовалось. Если память не изменяет, то вроде бы с CHECKSUM распределение более равномерно, без него есть определённый skew.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простенький тестовый [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e77079bd7dd73b36dbbd933dfb35338), в котором я генерирую 10.000 значений при помощи функции `NEWID()` и анализирую частотность первого символа GUID.

Пример значений (`select top(20) * from #guids;`):

```
UUID
F722B553-EABA-42CA-8E56-6EF34071651F
55C2BF49-543D-49C1-A75F-9D1850FABFAD
36DC258A-6545-4623-B139-1423A394AAF8
5FF078FC-5C22-4ED1-A9B7-448D34996394
5A653501-74C7-4A9A-9DBB-BAC797B987BA
90CE5C28-41A4-410A-AF47-D3E4529FCEA4
0BC67F34-4B10-4EDB-8B4E-B7BD7ED41235
F0E2E50B-123E-4A68-BB3E-F00B949D928A
4EFAFC75-0222-4CA3-BC7D-1B578BC60F60
1A8390F4-0734-4D8D-9641-51157DC672F2
11E1F65D-580E-440E-8DC6-E79158A75B75
7E5F1EBA-24AE-4663-BBD8-AE66519DF4E7
1526650B-5268-47AB-93DD-36465CE624DD
19B79A84-A13B-4E41-A288-C587689D49C9
D3B2F5EC-AC39-49F2-8FF7-3D1320E9526A
1193825C-3F39-47ED-9B7A-1880DAD7DFA8
0B237D0E-CD58-4EA1-A31B-250CB186C236
5C9F1821-DA95-4E77-8BFF-2EDE94E3407C
159EFB92-7985-4F38-AAE8-A8ADACFF74FB
8DF4491A-2030-452E-8A07-F074456294BD
```

частотность первого символа (`select * from #guids_stats order by counter desc;`):

```
first_letter    counter
7   6373
E   6340
3   6323
9   6318
4   6310
8   6288
A   6257
D   6257
C   6253
6   6250
1   6245
F   6227
5   6181
2   6162
0   6114
B   6102
```

Если разделить количество наименее часто встречающегося символа на количество наиболее часто встречающегося - получим `0.957476855484073`, т.е. около `4%`.

Вам решать насколько это "нормальное" распределение...
;)

Comment: в гуиде кроме псевдослучайного числа есть момент времени(системное время пк) когда была вызвана функция. и еще несколько постоянных компонент. случайная часть создается псевдослучайным генератором, а у них всегда есть период повторения, хоть и большой. так что все будет (наверное) зависеть от того сколько миллионов записей будет в таблице :D

Comment: @Yakov, вы имеете ввиду повторения компонента GUID или GUIDа целиком?

Comment: весь гуид целиком маловероятно (особенно если на разных компах, но вот если на одном пк слетит время, и начнут подряд создаваться множество гуидов, то в принципе вероятность, что они повторяться не нулевая), хотя человеческий фактор отменять нельзя, мы в 1с наталкивались на гуиды в одной базе созданные с одной датой (точнее пустой датой), как оказалось их сделали руками, а у нас приложение дату вычленяло из гуида, и по ней определяло дату запроса на сервер.